# Hide a portion of NSWindow (animation)

Tags: cocoa, animation, window, hide

I have a simple task with animating NSWindow, but still cannot find the way to accomplish this.

I have a Window that I want to hide by animating it beyond the screen edge. But with 2 displays connected, my window simply moves to the second monitor.

**Is there any way to make some clipping for the window to be drawn in the main screen rectangle area only?**

I haven't find anything like that in the Apple docs. And I know that some UI effects are achieved by making kind of tricks to simulate the desired behavior. Any info is much appreciated!

My first guess was to create a new window with secondary screen content snapshot. And then slide my main window under this snapshot. But this is a bad way - the content on the screen may animate (like video).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to have to resize it.

Obviously, resizing your real window won't work—you'd resize all of the views as side effects, and resizing any view to zero will tend to make it go bonkers.

So, you need to perform some sleight-of-hand:

1. [Take a screenshot of the window.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGWindowListCreateImage)
2. Create a borderless window whose frame size is exactly the size of that image. (Don't use the real window's frame—it won't include the shadow.)
3. Create an NSView to be the content view of the borderless window.
4. Create an image view and put it in the content view.
5. Set the image view's `autoresizingMask` to be sizable at the same edge of the view as the edge of the screen that you'll be animating the window out through. (For example, if you're animating the window off the bottom, make the bottom sizable.)

   Note that you want the width and height of the image view to be fixed—*not sizable*. You will change the size of the window, but you want the image view to remain the same size (and gradually disappear under the edge of the window).
6. If you've changed the real window's window level, set the borderless window's window level to match.
7. [Disable screen updates.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSDisableScreenUpdates)
8. [Order](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/orderWindow%3arelativeTo%3a) the borderless window [in front of](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/orderWindow%3arelativeTo%3a) the real window.
9. [Order out](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/orderOut%3a) the real window.
10. [Enable screen updates.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSEnableScreenUpdates)
11. Use either NSViewAnimation or Core Animation to animate the frame of the borderless window, changing its origin to the position of that screen edge, and the frame size on the relevant axis down to zero. Leave the other axis unchanged. For example, if you're animating off the right edge, change the x origin to the x coordinate of the screen's right edge, and the width to zero, and leave the y origin and height untouched.

    While you're at it, you may want to animate the window's `alphaValue` down to zero (NSViewAnimation calls this the “FadeOut” effect). Try it with and without this and see which way you prefer.
12. When the animation completes, order the borderless window out and throw it away.

Comment: Thanks @Peter! Your answer is very detailed. I am accepting it because a lot of users will find it very helpful. But I found a better solution for my case: instead of solving the drawing problem I better shift my window to the most left/top/right screen. I can see that all other application that hide themselves off the screen implement the same approach. But thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @UJey: What do you mean by “shift my window to the most left/top/right screen”? Isn't that the problem you were trying to solve?

Comment: when you have 2 screens, you always have an edge that lays between the screens. And that was the position of my window - on the main display, but between the screens. It was causing problems with window visibility on another display. Now, let's say, my secondary screen is on the right of the main. And my window should hide beyond  the right screen edge. So I am saying that I moved my window to be placed on the right edge of rightmost (secondary) screen, instead of being placed at the right border of the main screen. Ah, my words are confusing, but I guess you've got the idea.